# Extract action attribute in a Form tag with Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I wanna extract `https://www.sth.com/yment/Paymentform.aspx` from below string

```
<form id='paymentUTLfrm' action='https://www.sth.com/yment/Paymentform.aspx' method='post'>
```

How can I do it with `Regex` or somthing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I don't encourage using regex to parse HTML, this is simple enough that a regex will suffice. For more complex operations, do use a proper (X)HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack.

This regex should work:

```
<\s*form[^>]*\s+action=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

#### EDIT:

Updated regex so it will work with apostrophes in URLs. Note that the URL is now in the 2nd capture group.

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/iff9G3Tr1p)

Comment: Your regex is wrong for two reasons: ① Consider `<form action="blah'blah">` (yes, apostrophes are valid in URLs). ② Consider `<form action='x' m:special-action='x'>`.

Comment: @Mohammad That's what that capture group is there for. See on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/vNFS2AK0Ta), on the right-hand side there is a div with "match captures." Use those capture groups.

Comment: Yeah, but not the right x (bad example).  See [this example](http://rubular.com/r/aPYkNs29Wz).

Comment: @Timwi Fixed, although I've *never* seen either of those "in the wild."

Comment: OK, what other machinations do you have for my regex?

Comment: @NullUserException how can I extract the capture group with C# ?

Comment: When you have a match, access `.Groups[2]`.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, I've used this code 
`var action = Regex.Match(form, "<\\s*form[^>]*\baction=[\"']([^'\"]+)['\"]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups; foreach (var item in action) {Console.Write(item);}`
but it returns nothing !!!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;     
var doc = new HtmlDocument();                                       
doc.LoadHtml("<form id='paymentUTLfrm' action='https://www.sth.com/yment/Paymentform.aspx' method='post'>");      
var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("id('paymentUTLfrm')");
string action = form.Attributes["action"].Value;
```

It supports loading pages directly from the web, as well as XPath (used above).  The HTML does not have to be valid.

EDIT: If you want to use the name:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@name='paymentUTLfrm']");
```

Comment: great, thanks. if we don't have an `id` for the tag how we can do that then ? e.g : we have just name attribute instead.

Comment: Is `SelectSingleNode` case sensitive ?

Comment: @Mohammad, in HtmlAgilityPack, the `id` is case-insensitive.  To make the `@name` match case-insensitive, you can use a hack [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279513/how-can-i-create-a-nokogiri-case-insensitive-xpath-selector/2279611#2279611).

Answer (score 0):

While I would agree that general html parsing is best done with html agility pack (etc) rather than with regex, this is a pretty simple requirement and a regex would be appropriate. I am no regex expert, but this one works:

```
action=["'](.*)["']
```

The (.*) will capture the url

maybe some expert can add a comnent to refine this...

Comment: Your regex is greedy and will cause problems

Comment: Specifically, for this example it will match `action='https://www.sth.com/yment/Paymentform.aspx' method='post'`

Comment: Hence the disclaimer and request for refinement - I don't think providiing an idea for an alternate approach, even if not perfect, is cause for a downvote. @Matthew - I really think html agility pack is overkill for the OP's need. @Null - your regex actually works (as compared to mine) - I learned something - thanx.