# How to use Regex expression in Capybara have_css/have_selector?

Tags: ruby, regex, capybara, nokogiri

In Rspec Capybara test I want to check that no *H4*, *H5*, ..., *H9* selector exists.

I would expect the following solution:

```
visit "/"
expect(page).not_to have_css(/(h|H)\[4-9]d/)
```

But it fails due to Nokogiri parsing

I also noticed that:

```
has_css?("h1")

# is not equal to

has_css?("H1")
```

Comment: why not just "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9". I'm not aware that nokogiri takes regex selectors at all. If you are too lazy to type them out you could do `Array(1..9).map { |n| 'h' + n.to_s }.join(',')`

Comment: @papirtiger This is what I do, but there should be a better way to test it. I think that has_css? should be case insensitive.

Comment: How is that really an issue unless you are testing HTML from 1995?

Comment: I should verify that specific page doesn't have H* tags (SEO requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives:

### 1. Just create a slightly ugly expectation and get it done:

```
visit "/"
expect(page).not_to have_css("h1,H1,h2,H2,h3,H3,h4,H4,h5,H5,h6,H6,h7,H7,h8,H8,h9,H9")
```

I used the following snippet to generate that ugly selector:

```
(1..9).map { |n| "h#{n.to_s},H#{n.to_s}" }.join(',')
```

### 2. Create a case insensitive XPath selector:

[How can I create a nokogiri case insensitive Xpath selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279513/how-can-i-create-a-nokogiri-case-insensitive-xpath-selector)

### 3. Use [Nokogumbo](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo)

Nokogumbo is a HTML5 parser which creates lowercase element names.